# mysql LIKE operator not matching the condition appropriately

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm using a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE token LIKE 'v_%'
```

This is resulting in records whose token starts with `v_` (which is exactly what I want) but it is also showing records which start with just `v` (screenshot attached)

[image]

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to `_` because it is a wildcard

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE token LIKE 'v\_%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d197d/1)

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE token LIKE 'v|_%' ESCAPE '|';
```

- [MySQL LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: Nice. +1 and accepting as answer. Got to learn a new thing today.